# Curve Snap and normal align to face in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I'm new to Blender Geometry Nodes and have following problem:

I want to add a Geometry Nodes modifier to a curve that enables its both endpoints to snap to the faces of some designated simple planes and also align the curve handles to the normal of the corresponding face.

What I have:

With only one endpoint it works, when I grab and drag the plane to the endpoint it snaps with the given snapping distance and also aligns the normal.

What does not work:

When I duplicate this node (and set the endpoints to the other end) the snapping of the opposite curve endpoint is disabled when I only have one plane like expected, but the normal alignment still triggers what I do not want to have since the plane is far away.
It should only align when the curve is snapped to the face.

What I tried:
I wanted to simply use a switch node to tell the normal alignment part (sample nearest surface) to ignore the face when its far away. The problem is the control of the switch node, since it has a circular input but my distance checking node gives a diamond output.
Can I somehow just extract the boolean value of the "Not node" after the Snapping distance node?

[image]

[image]

**Addendum**:

To anyone to whom this also might be useful to: I have further adapted this geometry nodes group so that it is able to snap to a collection of plane objects:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use boolean math to "and" with your snapping option like this:

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

> Note: i apologize for my messy node setup

> Note 2: if you can do this with geometry nodes, your are not (!) new
> to geometry nodes!!

Comment: Oh Yes! Thank you so much that did the trick :) I'm experimentig now for a few weeks around with geo nodes, piecing together stuff I need for my project using tutorials from youtube and all around the internet but many concepts of node editing are still new to me.

Comment: They AND nodes all have the same inputs, right? You would just need a single one of them, not three.

Comment: @Leander: thx, you are totally right